# Efficient structure for XML manipulation

Tags: customization, xml

I'm interested in working with XML more conveniently and efficiently than I currently can. The standard [`XMLDocument`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XMLDocument.html)/[`XMLElement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/XMLElement.html) structure is incredibly inefficient.

My thought was to move to something like:

```
XMLGraph[nodeGraph_Graph, nodeData_Association]
```

where the `nodeGraph` is the tree structure of the XML and the `nodeData` is an `Association` of data referenced into by the `nodeGraph`.

I could then define standard access/mutation mechanisms that'd be efficient and also allow me to do use [`BreadthFirstScan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BreadthFirstScan.html) and things for parsing, as well as immediately extract node data from the `Association`.

Can anyone think of a better way? (Or think of a clean way to implement this?)

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to focus on the convenience part of the question. [jsoupLink](https://github.com/cekdahl/jSoupLink) can work well for a lot of situations. Let's say, for example, that we want to parse RSS. RSS is an XML format, so we can do it like this:

```
<< jSoupLink`
root = Import["http://packagedata.net/index.php/feed", "HTMLDOM"]
items = root["Select", "item"];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What this shows is that using jSoupLink, we can often retrieve information with a much cleaner syntax than if we were using Mathematica's symbolic XML.

jsoupLink can also modify elements. Here's an example of how we can build an SVG, which is also an XML format, iteratively:

```
root = ImportString[
   "<svg  xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\"></svg>",
   "HTMLDOM"
   ];
svg = First[root["Select", "svg"]];

Do[
  svg[
   "Append",
   "<circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"10\" fill=\"blue\"/>"],
  {10}
  ];

Export["~/Desktop/test.svg", svg, "HTMLDOM"]
```

If we look at this SVG file in a browser, we see the following (posted here as a PNG):

[image: Example]

All the disks are on top of each other and of the same color. We can now also use jsoupLink to shift them around and change their color:

```
circles = svg["Select", "circle"];
Do[
  Part[circles, i]["Attribute", "cx", ToString@RandomReal[100]];
  Part[circles, i]["Attribute", "cy", ToString@RandomReal[100]];
  Part[circles, i]["Attribute", "fill", Image`Utilities`toHEXcolor@ColorData[97, i]];
  ,
  {i, Length[circles]}
  ];

ExportString[svg, "HTMLDOM"]

(* Out:

"<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" \
xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" width=\"300\" \
height=\"300\">
 <circle cx=\"39.6123\" cy=\"98.7366\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#5e81b5\" />
 <circle cx=\"42.4556\" cy=\"71.0983\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#e19c24\" />
 <circle cx=\"26.9683\" cy=\"9.98416\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#8fb032\" />
 <circle cx=\"36.7453\" cy=\"66.7649\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#eb6235\" />
 <circle cx=\"94.7156\" cy=\"21.069\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#8778b3\" />
 <circle cx=\"77.1975\" cy=\"61.0884\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#c56e1a\" />
 <circle cx=\"21.5307\" cy=\"24.9411\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#5d9ec7\" />
 <circle cx=\"13.0563\" cy=\"62.826\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#ffbf00\" />
 <circle cx=\"24.5768\" cy=\"57.8981\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#a5609d\" />
 <circle cx=\"24.2052\" cy=\"21.9666\" r=\"10\" fill=\"#929600\" />
</svg>"

*)
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: That is very convenient. How easy is it to get out properties, like scan for a certain XML structure pattern?

Comment: @b3m2a1 That's what the `node["Select", "css selector"]` function is for. CSS selectors excel at describing how elements relate to each other hierarchically.

Comment: Ahh. Very nice. One fun thing, I see you have some property assignment syntax like `circles[[i]]["Attribute", "cx", ToString@RandomReal[100]]`, have you thought about using the new `MutationHandler` stuff to make that more standard? e.g. you could do `node["name"]=val` and it'd unwrap to `node["Attribute", "name", ToString@val]`? Maybe also supporting `AssociateTo`. In any case, as far as convenience goes I think that'd be about as convenient as it comes, right? The `MutationHandler` would be necessary for things like when `node` has been assigned to a variable.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I just heard about `MutationHandler` yesterday (from you) and I don't know what it is yet but that sounds like exactly what I would like to do actually. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

C.E.'s answer is probably the best, relying as it does on a well-constructed Java library with serious people behind it, but I thought it'd be nice to have a pure Mathematica solution as well, so I sunk some time into building an `XMLGraph` object which I put [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/XMLGraph.m).

The basic idea is to store the two pieces of data I talked about before, a `Graph` that holds all of the structural relationships, and an `Association` encoding all of the data as a flat data structure.

Each node then gets a name, e.g. `"head:ee1d9544"` which goes into the `Graph` and an entry in the `Association` like:

```
<|
  "Parent" -> "html:80da223b",
  "Type" -> "head",
  "Name" -> "head:ee1d9544",
  "Meta" -> <||>,
  "Children" -> {}
|>
```

This way it's easy to mutate the object by changing entries in the flat association and it's easy to query the `Graph` to get out structure.

I then used this to implement conversion from `XMLElement` and CSS selectors, so here's a little rundown of what we can do (although development work isn't finished):

```
Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/XMLGraph.m"];

testXML = 
  Import["https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes",
   {"HTML", "XMLObject"}
   ];

g = XMLGraph[testXML]
```

[image]

Then we can query, say, all the `code` elements that follow a `td` element (this was what originally spurred me to make this). The Mathematica code for this query in the standard way looks like:

```
t1 = Cases[testXML, 
  XMLElement["td", _, code_] :> 
   FirstCase[code, XMLElement["code", _, {s_, ___}] :> s, 
    Nothing, \[Infinity]], \[Infinity]];
```

The graph query looks like:

```
t2 = First /@ Values@
  g@"Children"[g@"Select"["td code"]];

DeleteDuplicates@Sort@t1 == DeleteDuplicates@Sort@t2

True
```

Performance-wise we're a bit slower:

```
t1 = Cases[testXML, 
    XMLElement["td", _, code_] :> 
     FirstCase[code, XMLElement["code", _, {s_, ___}] :> s, 
      Nothing, \[Infinity]], \[Infinity]]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.00045, Null}

t2 = First /@ Values@
     g@"Children"[g@"Select"["td code"]]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.0091, Null}
```

But other things like property look-ups are so much faster like this. Also we can do queries over the `Association` instead of the graph (when possible) which is competitive with `Cases`:

```
Cases[testXML, 
   XMLElement["code", _, _], \[Infinity]]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.00015, Null}

nodes = g@"Select"["code"]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.00077, Null}
```

And once we have this set of nodes it's easy and fast to get all sorts of information out:

```
g@"Children"[nodes]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.00012, Null}

g@"Parent"[nodes]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.000082, Null}

g@"Attribute"[nodes, "colspan"]; // RepeatedTiming

{0.000084, Null}
```

This is rather more challenging to do well with `XMLElement`.

We can also do easy modifications like this:

```
newG = g@"ModifyNodes"[
    Thread[nodes -> <|"colspan" -> 2|>]
    ];

g@"Attribute"[nodes, "colspan"] // Take[#, 5] &

<|"td:ae4c93a0" -> "1", "td:c3fbb1ce" -> "1", "td:77adbfa1" -> "1", 
 "td:3efd9c29" -> "1", "td:69452f14" -> "1"|>

newG@"Attribute"[nodes, "colspan"] // Take[#, 5] &

<|"td:ae4c93a0" -> 2, "td:c3fbb1ce" -> 2, "td:77adbfa1" -> 2, 
 "td:3efd9c29" -> 2, "td:69452f14" -> 2|>
```

Or we can change some types and dump to XML:

```
mods = {newG["Root"] -> <|"Type" -> "xml"|>};
newG@"ModifyNodes"[mods]@"XML" // Shallow

XMLElement["xml", <|"version" -> 
   "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN", "lang" -> "en", 
  "prefix" -> 
   "og: http://ogp.me/ns#", {"http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", 
    "xmlns"} -> "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"|>, {XMLElement[<<3>>], 
  XMLElement[<<3>>]}]
```

The full list of supported methods is somewhat in flux, but it'll be exposed eventually and every method has a `Symbol` backing it (e.g. `` XMLGraph`Package`SelectNodes `` for `"Select"`) so that's always possible to look at.

As a final usage note, with the structure as it's set-up the storage can always be handled by as [`HashTable`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184215/making-an-association-like-interface-for-hashtable) which would allow this `XMLGraph` to be a truly mutable object in the way the object-oriented interface suggests it could be.

Hopefully this gives a sense of how this may be done and why this type of structure is useful. And of course, this is a preliminary package, so performance enhancements are always possible.