# Making an Association-like interface for HashTable

Tags: customization, undocumented, language-design

`` System`Utilities`HashTable `` is conceptually a lot like an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) but it has the pretty phenomenal (for Mathematica) property that it's properly mutable. What I mean is that if we have a hash-table and bind it to a variable, assign it to a new variable, and mutate it there, we get the changes showing up on our original hash-table:

```
ht = System`Utilities`HashTable[]

System`Utilities`HashTable["<" 0 ">"]

b = ht;
System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[ht, "key", val];
ht

System`Utilities`HashTable["<" 1 ">"]
```

By contrast `Association` copies itself on assignment so this doesn't work:

```
ht = <||>;
b = ht;
b["key"] = val;
ht

<||>
```

For this an other efficiency-related reasons I'd like to use `HashTable` a lot more than I currently do.

One stumbling block is that the interface is annoying to use, to say the least.

Can we make this work a lot more like `Association`?

Comment: The real problem seems to be, that this "is conceptually a lot like an Association" is just not true, because for an assoc immutability is probably the defining property. The API for  `Association` is rather large, because it is integrated well with the language (so supports things like `Map`, `Join`, etc.). All that is only possible because it is immutable. For hash table being mutable, the only option you have is to may be add some interface to standard create, put, get,  contains operations. Anything else, mixing it with immutable expressions, will probably just be a lot of pain at the end.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I think there is a use case, though, for a mutable `HashTable` with reasonable integration into the language. It doesn't have to be `Association` quality, but really just decent is good enough. Mutability is a useful property if you know what you're doing and so good enough is still very useful.

Comment: The problem with mutability is that the language is not optimized for it. This means both the lack of efficiency and the lack of wide support through the language. Mixing mutable and immutable programming styles is hard and error-prone, and requires non-trivial amount of experience with the language. But in any case, making an interface for a mutable structure mimic that of an assoc, will probably not serve well most of the users. For example, in your answer you apply the "Map" function and then see a change in the original one - and IMO this is just wrong, `Map` should not have side effects.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin For me, lack of mutability in the language is my *least* favorite part of Mathematica. Both in my own work and what I've seen across the site, people are often re-inventing OOP in limited, fragile fashion *because* there's no mutability, which is even less efficient. Also, while lack of efficiency is an issue, I think it just means that one has to be more clever in programming constructs. Push things that need efficiency into functions that handle the data well and whatnot. OTOH, I agree that `Map` the function shouldn't mutate a structure, but `"Map"` the method can.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the sample package I've been working on. It simply defines the standard `Association` functions to work with `HashTable` in some reasonably efficient way.

You can get it off GitHub:

```
Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/HashTableInterface.m"]
```

Making a `HashTable` uses `Association` as an interface layer, so anything `Association` can be initialed from, `HashTable` can be initialized from too. Here's some sample usage:

```
ht = HashTable@{1 -> 2, 3 -> 4}
(*Out:*)
HashTableInterface`HashTable[System`Utilities`HashTable[1, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]]

Keys@ht
(*Out:*)
{3, 1}

Normal@ht
(*Out:*)
<|3 -> 4, 1 -> 2|>

AssociationMap[Reverse, ht] // Normal
(*Out:*)
<|4 -> 3, 2 -> 1|>

ht@"Map"[# + 1 &]
ht // Normal
(*Out:*)
<|3 -> 5, 1 -> 3|>
```

I added some formatting and things as well.

The real power of this approach is seen in that last line. I added a `"Map"` method to the `HashTable` which allows the object itself to be mutated via `Map` instead of creating a new object.

That opens the doors for OOP and other things.